# Trying to resolve builder-pattern from java to apex

Tags: java, salesforce, apex, builder-pattern

`I've been studying a builder pattern and run into a problem during writing a code from Java to Apex. It works on Java, but something goes wrong on Apex

Here's my Apex - classes.

```
`public class Chiller {

    private double coolingCapacity;
    private double compressorPower;
    private double EER;
    RefrigerationType refrigerationType;

    public void setCoolingCapacity(double coolingCapacity) {
        this.coolingCapacity = coolingCapacity;
    }

    public void setCompressorPower(double compressorPower) {
        this.compressorPower = compressorPower;
    }

    public void setEER(double EER) {
        this.EER = EER;
    }

    public void setRefrigerationType(RefrigerationType refrigerationType) {
        this.refrigerationType = refrigerationType;
    }

    public override String toString() {
        return 'Chiller [Cooling capacity = ' + coolingCapacity + ' compressor power input = ' + compressorPower + ' EER = ' + Math.round(EER) +
                ' refrigeration type is ' + refrigerationType + ']';
    }
}
```

public enum RefrigerationType {R134, R12}

```
public abstract class ChillerBuilder {
    Chiller chiller;
    public void createChiller() {
        chiller = new Chiller();
    }

    public abstract void buildCapacity();
    public abstract void buildCompressorPower();
    public abstract void buildEER();
    public abstract void buildRefrigerationType ();

    Chiller getChiller() {
        return chiller;
    }
}
```

```
public class ScrewBuilder extends ChillerBuilder {
    public override void buildCapacity() {
        chiller.setCoolingCapacity(((12-7)*1042*1000/3600));
    }
    public override void buildCompressorPower() {
        chiller.setCompressorPower(((12-7)*1042*1000/3600)*0.83);
    }
    public override void buildEER() {
        chiller.setEER(((12-7)*1042*1000/3600)/(((12-7)*1042*1000/3600)*0.83));
    }
    public override void buildRefrigerationType() {
        chiller.setRefrigerationType(RefrigerationType.R134);
    }
}
```

```
public class Director {
    ChillerBuilder builder;
    void setBuilder(ChillerBuilder b) {
        builder = b;
    }

    Chiller BuildChiller() {
        builder.createChiller();
        builder.buildCapacity();
        builder.buildCompressorPower();
        builder.buildEER();
        builder.buildRefrigerationType();
        Chiller chiller = builder.getChiller();
        return chiller;
    }
}`
```

Problems seems like in ScrewBuilder Class variables are not visible in line with setters
chiller.setCoolingCapacity(((12-7)*1042*1000/3600));
Could you help me with this?
Thanks in advance!`

```
I tried to re-write access fields to public everywhere but it doesn't help
```

Answer (score -1):

`Chiller chiller;` - without the public/protected/private this thing becomes private. Meaning nobody else can use it, even child classes that extend from you.

If you'd make it [protected](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_access_modifiers.htm) the value should become visible in `ScrewBuilder`